# Unexpected extension byte (at offset 1014), with utf8.decode()

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8, decode

I'm read a `csv` file using `file_picker` package and then to read data I'm using this code

```
final decodedString = utf8.decode(file.bytes);
```

This gives me the following error.

```
Unexpected extension byte (at offset 1014)
```

When I set `allowMalformed: true`, I didn't get the error but the data was not complete, and it missed a lot of rows in the `csv` file.

```
final decodedString = utf8.decode(file.bytes, allowMalformed: true);
```

I have come across a lot of solutions and have tried decoding using `latin1` as well but still, the data wasn't complete.

**Some relevant information to share**

I wrote a program in Python to double check if there was something wrong with the file and it gave me a similar error.

**Python code**

```
import csv
import unicodedata

def unicode_csv_reader(utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)

filename = 'da.csv'
reader = unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))
```

**Error**

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 1014: invalid start byte
```

**Working Solution**

I was able to resolve it by setting the `errors` parameter in the `open` function.

```
open(filename, errors="ignore")
```

I was expecting `allowMalformed` in `utf8.decode()` to fix this just like `errors`, but to my surprise, the results are very different.

Comment: Without the data, all we can say is the data is being decoded with the wrong encoding, or the data has some bad encodings.  What are examples of the badly decoded and correctly decoded text?  `A0` is typically a `latin1` or `windows-125x` encoding of `NO-BREAK SPACE`.

Comment: I have identified that there is a particular cell that causing the problem. That has confused me even more. The data does not seem to be malformed and why does it work fine in Python?

Comment: Add the encoded byte data of that cell to your question

Comment: UTF-8 decoders are supposed to fail (as default) in case of encoded surrogates, using a "overlong encoding" (so not the most efficient way to encode a single character), and using values outside Unicode range. [All of that for good security reasons] So maybe you encountered one of such case

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'll share

Comment: @MarkTolonen Not sure what you're asking about.
The error occurs at the index 1014, and at that, the integer value is 99.

Comment: Need context.  `99` by itself is definitely not a UTF-8 encoding, but may need the whole sentence or paragraph to guess what character it is supposed to be.  for example, 0x99 in Windows-1252 encoding is `TRADE MARK SIGN` (™), so you may need `open(filename, encoding='Windows-1252')`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen 99 is normal UTF-8 code unit, it decoded as is 99. Code point ↔ UTF-8 conversion: U+0000 U+007F 0xxxxxxx. I mean decimal value 99.

Comment: @mezoni That wouldn't cause an error at that offset then, but 0x99 (hexadecimal, which OP wasn't clear about but makes the most sense) would be an "unexpected extension byte".

Comment: @MarkTolonen  Where you found 0x99?. Please, reread author comment. It wrote 99 but not a 0x99. You are very strange. How you know that 99 == 0x99. 99 is decimal but 0x99 is hexadecimal. `Please tell me where you found 0x99` on this page. => `@MarkTolonen Not sure what you're asking about. The error occurs at the index 1014, and at that, the integer value is 99.`

Comment: @MarkTolonen UTF-8 has more than one extension byte. How do you know that 99 is the first byte of the extension? Maybe it's the second or third byte of the extension?

Comment: Second, third and fourth extension bytes has a mask 0x3f (63). 99 > 63. Do not you take this into account?

Comment: 0x99 is an extension byte because it starts with 10xxxxxx in binary. The error message indicates the error was an unexpected extension byte. 99 decimal would not be an extension byte.  I am assuming the OP meant 99 hexadecimal or it wouldn’t have caused the error. Ideally, the OP should be explicit and also provide more context, like the bytes before the error as well.